# Grub file filters not found after upgraded to latest ubuntu version

Tags: grub2, upgrade, grubrescue, grub-efi, grub-legacy

Grub file filters not found even after tried using insmod normal.
Please tell me an solution to fix this without any hardware support

Comment: It's best if you're specific as to what you consider the *latest* release of Ubuntu.  To me that's the 21.04 or 2021-April release of Ubuntu, however many users on this site seem to count only LTS releases, thus the *latest* is technically the third-latest, or 20.04 LTS - so please be specific.

Comment: It's 21.04 version